# What terminal library could be used in cygwin?

Tags: terminal, cygwin

I am using Cygwin to compile Vim, but the configure script tells me that there is no terminal library in the Cygwin environment. Which terminal library could be installed in Cypwin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install `ncurses` in Cygwin.

(You can also install `vim`; I presume you have a reason to build it from source rather than using the provided version.)

I just installed vim 7.3 under Cygwin.  Here's what I did (approximately):

- Download [vim-7.3.tar.bz2](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/unix/vim-7.3.tar.bz2)
- `tar xf vim-7.3.tar.bz2`
- `cd vim73`
- `./configure --prefix=`*/path/to/installation/directory*
- `make`
- `make install`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just want to do some experiments on my private build.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but installing the `ncurses` (and `libncurses`) Cygwin package isn't working for me... What do I need to do to get the configure script to run?

Comment: Thanks @KeithThompson: It's still not working for me :( I'm trying to compile Vim with Python support ([instructions here](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2004-06/msg00540.html)), but it's still failing at the ncurses hurdle: I have both the ncurses and ncursesw packages installed, as well as their lib counterparts... Should the `prefix` be where Vim should ultimately end up (i.e., /usr/local/bin)?

Comment: @Xophmeister: If you want vim in /usr/local/bib, the prefix should be `/usr/local` -- but that's not the cause of your problem. You should probably post a new question with the command you used, the exact error message, and the relevant packages you've installed.

Comment: Good plan!... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959243/building-vim-from-source-in-cygwin