# Building Vim from Source in Cygwin

Tags: python, vim, build, cygwin, ncurses

I am trying to build Vim from the source packages, under Cygwin, to enable Python support. I am following the instructions given [here](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2004-06/msg00540.html), but I'm hitting this error when I run the `configure` script:

```
checking --with-tlib argument... empty: automatic terminal library selection
checking for tgetent in -lncurses... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermlib... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermcap... no
checking for tgetent in -lcurses... no
no terminal library found
checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

The Vim source package gets downloaded as `/usr/src/vim-7.3.tar.gz`, which I extract and then attempt to build using:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-multibyte --without-x --enable-gui=no --enable-pythoninterp
```

The `prefix` option was suggested in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322238/what-terminal-library-could-be-used-in-cygwin), where the OP is having the exact same problem. However, I installed the `ncurses` Cygwin package (and also `ncursesw`), as well as their library equivalents, so I'm not sure what's going wrong for me (i.e., why the `configure` script can't find them). I've tried explicitly setting the `--with-tlib` argument (e.g., `--with-tlib=/bin/cygncurses-10.dll`, `ncurses`, `libncurses10` and `libncurses`), but it fails in the same place with something like:

```
checking for linking with libncurses10 library... configure: error: FAILED
```

The `ncurses` packages I have installed are:

- libncursesw10 (5.7-18)
- libncurses10 (5.7-18)
- libncurses9 (5.7-16)
- libncurses8 (5.5-10)
- ncurses (5.7-18)
- ncursesw (5.7-18)

All suggestions welcome!!

Comment: I'm running the exact same `./configure ...` command on my own system (Windows 7, Cygwin).  It hasn't finished, but I have `checking for tgetent in -lncurses... yes`.

Comment: Look in `src/auto/config.log` and search for `tgetent`; that will tell you more about how `./configure` decided that you don't have `tgetent`.

Comment: If you're using a 64-bit OS, consider the [pre-compiled native build](http://code.google.com/p/vim-win3264/) which has Python 2.7 support included (through dynamic loading, so it must be able to find the Python DLL).

Comment: [Another case, `libncurses-devel` already installed, but failed to find `tgetent`. ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146370/cygwin-vim-configure-missing-terminal-library-for-example-ncurses/76174741#76174741)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're missing a required package.  Lengthy explanation follows; jump to the end for the answer.

I ran the exact same `./configure ...` command on my own system (Windows 7, Cygwin).  Part of its output was:

```
checking for tgetent in -lncurses... yes
```

which indicates that I don't have the same problem you have.

The `configure` script writes a more verbose log to `src/auto/config.log`.  On my system, that shows:

```
configure:9777: checking for tgetent in -lncurses
configure:9802: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c -lncurses  -lelf   >&5
configure:9802: $? = 0
configure:9812: result: yes
```

The `-lncurses` option tells the linker to look at `/usr/lib/libncurses.`*foo*, where *.foo* can be `.a`, or `.so`, or `.dll`, depending on the system and whether you're doing dynamic linking.  On Cygwin, the `cygcheck` command can tell you which package owns a specified file or files.  On my system:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/libncurses.*
/usr/lib/libncurses.a  /usr/lib/libncurses.dll.a  /usr/lib/libncurses.la
$ cygcheck -f /usr/lib/libncurses.*
libncurses-devel-5.7-18
libncurses-devel-5.7-18
libncurses-devel-5.7-18
```

I believe that installing `libncurses-devel` (via the Cygwin [`setup.exe`](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe)) should fix your problem.

Comment: Sir, you are both a gentleman and a scholar! Building now... Thank you :)

Comment: Just finished building: Works perfectly :) Thanks again

Comment: Hi @KeithThompson, I've met the vim+python problem also. [Here is my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349930/how-can-i-add-with-python-options-by-building-gvim-vim-from-source-code-in-wi). I've installed `lubncurses` in cygwin by following your way, but nothing changed. 0 still shows in `:echo has('python')`. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: awesome, thanks!

`apt-cyg install libncurses-devel`
And then confirmed with:
`cygcheck -f /usr/lib/libncurses.*`
Resolved for me the `tgetent()` error on MobaXterm