# building vim for cygwin--no terminal library

Tags: vim, cygwin, ncurses

I'm trying to build vim with python support for cygwin using:

```
./configure --enable-pythoninterp --enable-gui=no --without-x \
--enable-multibyte --prefix=/usr
```

but can't get around the error:

```
checking --with-tlib argument... empty: automatic terminal library selection
checking for tgetent in -lncurses... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermlib... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermcap... no
checking for tgetent in -lcurses... no
no terminal library found
checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

I do have libncurses-devel installed (so this is different than SO question [Building Vim from Source in Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959243/building-vim-from-source-in-cygwin))

I've also tried adding a `--with-tlib=ncurses` flag with the same results.

Anyone have any suggestions for getting vim to recognize the libncurses library?

+++++++++++++Possibly relevant info++++++++++++++++

Excerpts from auto\config.log:

```
configure:9897: result: no
configure:9903: checking --with-tlib argument
configure:9938: result: empty: automatic terminal library selection
configure:9946: checking for tgetent in -ltinfo
configure:9971: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c -ltinfo   >&5
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ltinfo
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:9971: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:

...

configure:9981: result: no
configure:9946: checking for tgetent in -lncurses
configure:9971: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c -lncurses   >&5
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lncurses
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:9971: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
configure:9981: result: no

...

configure:9946: checking for tgetent in -ltermlib
configure:9971: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c -ltermlib   >&5
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ltermlib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:9971: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:

...

configure:9981: result: no
configure:9946: checking for tgetent in -ltermcap
configure:9971: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c -ltermcap   >&5
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ltermcap
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:9971: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:

...

configure:9981: result: no
configure:9946: checking for tgetent in -lcurses
configure:9971: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c -lcurses   >&5
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurses
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:9971: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:

...

configure:9981: result: no
configure:10027: result: no terminal library found
configure:10033: checking for tgetent()
configure:10046: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c  >&5
C:\cygwin\tmp\cc4wgcbm.o: In function `main':
C:\Temp\vim\src/conftest.c:46: undefined reference to `tgetent'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:10046: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:

configure:10052: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

ls /usr/lib/libncurses.*

```
/usr/lib/libncurses.a /usr/lib/libncurses.dll.a /usr/lib/libncurses.la
```

Comment: Oops! Looks like I did not have some of the libncurses sources installed (though I thought I had). Unfortunately, I took a shotgun approach and installed sources for all ncurses/libncurses packages (and also added a few gcc packages), so I'm not 100% sure which was required, but I assume it was the libncurses-devel source.

Configure and make are working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Oops!  Looks like I did not have some of the libncurses sources installed (though I thought I had).  Unfortunately, I took a shotgun approach and installed sources for all ncurses/libncurses packages (and also added a few gcc packages), so I'm not 100% sure which was required, but I assume it was the libncurses-devel source.

*Note: initially answered in comment above due to SO's waiting period before new users can answer their own questions*

Comment: I can confirm that installing libncurses-devel is enough to solve this problem. However I interpret the log messages as that there are other solutions.

Comment: but any one can help me to add `+clientserver` feature in configure?