# Cygwin/VIM configure: missing terminal library (for example ncurses)

Tags: c++, vim, terminal, cygwin

I've worked for 6 hours on this problem now, but I still can't figure out more, than the command I have now (after looking at solutions online and answers to other poor people who had this problem).

I try to build the vim editor on Windows+Cygwin with python3 and mingw32 installed (default commands as g++, c++,... all reference to specific commands like 'i686-w64-mingw32-c++')

As many other people, I've got the error, that a terminal library is missing (for example ncurses).

After many hours of trying to configure the vim project, I'm still stuck.
I have already tried to:

- Change toolchain to cygwin packages (switched back to custom mingw32 installation)
- Installed different version of ncurses (with libraries copied to different locations as **/usr/lib**, **/usr/local/lib**, **/lib**)
- Written the **./configure** command differently several times

**My current configure statement:**

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/cygdrive/d/developtools/mingw32/lib ./configure 
    --with-features=huge \
    --enable-multibyte \
    --enable-python3interp=yes \
    --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-cygwin \
    --enable-cscope \
    --with-tlib=ncurses
```

**Part of my current config.log file**

```
configure:11342: result: no
configure:11348: checking --with-tlib argument
configure:11357: result: ncurses
configure:11360: checking for linking with ncurses library
configure:11373: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c  -lncurses >&5
configure:11373: $? = 0
configure:11374: result: OK
configure:11477: checking for tgetent()
configure:11490: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c  -lncurses >&5
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:49:26: warning: implicit declaration of function 'tgetent' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 char s[10000]; int res = tgetent(s, "thisterminaldoesnotexist");
                          ^~~~~~~
```

I also have been thinking, if the same error message (of needing a terminal library) is just produced, because there seems to be something wrong with the declaration (or definition) of `tgetent`.

**And finally still the same error message**

```
configure:11494: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

Has anyone had the same problem while working on windows in cygwin, while using a custom installation of a toolchain?

Thank you in advance. If you need more information, feel free to ask.

---

**EDIT(11.07.2017, 11:35-CH)**

This is my first error, which justs repeat several times during the configure process:

```
configure:3503: gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:10:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
configure:3503: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define UNIX 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:3528: result: gcc -E
```

---

**EDIT(11.07.2017, 13:42-CH)**

With [babun](http://babun.github.io) I was finally able to run `configure` vim. But while running `make` I got another error:

```
Starting make in the src directory.
If there are problems, cd to the src directory and run make there
cd src && D:/developtools/mingw32/bin/mingw32-make first
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/developtools/.babun/cygwin/home/tobbe/vim/src'
gcc -c -I.   -I/usr/include/python2.7 -DPYTHON_HOME='"/usr"' -pthread -fPIE    -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1        -o objects/option.o option.c
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Makefile:3215: recipe for target 'objects/option.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [objects/option.o] Error 1
```

I have already looked into objects directory and actually option.o was not created.

Comment: look on the cywin source package to see how the maintainer is configuring the vim build. `tgetent` seems an obsolete interface http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/tgetent.html

Comment: ncurses provides that *entrypoint*, but the warning is about a header file.  Cygwin's packager (like a few others) may have decided that `termcap.h` was unnecessary.  The warning does not prevent the configure script from working. The question does not show the first **error**.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I now edited my question and added the first error. But I thought, because the configure checks many things beforehand, this would be just given.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Ok. I tried with the babun overlay for cygwin and I could configure then. But now I have a different error on running `make`. Error message is in edit.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter same issue recently.
On cygwin vim's `./configure` fail with below message.

```
checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      On Linux that would be the libncurses-dev package.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

But `libncurses-dev` is already installed.

After search around, checking `src/auto/config.log` as suggested by [here](https://groups.google.com/g/vim_dev/c/3zR-hLaGIFA)

```
configure:11931: checking for tgetent in -lcurses
configure:11956: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c -lcurses   -lselinux >&5
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lselinux: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

then goto `/usr/lib` && `/usr/local/lib`

```
ls -l /usr/lib /usr/local/lib
/usr/lib:
total 109995
... libncurses.a libncurses.dll.a ...
/usr/local/lib:
total 0
python3.8
```

Now found the reason, `libncurses` is at `/usr/lib`, but somehow the `./configure` use `/usr/local/lib`, let's add link flag.
In this case, after prepend `./configure` with `LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib"` , it build successfully. Below is new output in `src/auto/config.log`

```
configure:11931: checking for tgetent in -lncursesw
configure:11956: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2  -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c -lncursesw    >&5
configure:11956: $? = 0
configure:11966: result: yes
```

Also, on cygwin, to build vim, make sure below packages being installed at a minimum.

```
make automake libncurses-devel gcc-g++ cscope python3-devel
```

a little more info:

```
automake automatically add autoconf
gcc-g++ automatically add gcc-core
libncurses-devel automatically add pkg-config libncursesw10 libncurses++w10
```